# Parse XML closing tag in iOS (Objective C)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

I want to identify a closing tag from my xml response. For example,

```
<ItemLocationResponse xxxx>
    <UserProfile>
        blah blah contents..
    </UserProfile>
    <UserProfile>
        blah blah contents..
    </UserProfile>
</ItemLocationResponse>
```

I want to identify the closing tag . Currently i am able to parse the data containing in an opening tag. From the above example, i can parse the data containing in "blah blah contents" from each opening tags . I tried much for getting the closing tag  for identifying that the xml response has been ended. So how can i identify the closing tag  has been came over?

Comment: Do you mean getting XML attributes? (http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp)

Comment: Are you using a parser or rolling your own custom solution - why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSXMLParser` for xml parsing in iOS.

```
NSXMLParser * parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];
```

Implement its delegate methods to get xml's elements.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
//Called when any element which having opening and closing element and its closed called

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
//if tag having value then this method is called.

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it easy, use [XMLDictionary](https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary).